# How to give infixities to operators in lambda?

Tags: haskell, syntax, lambda, infix-notation, infix-operator

For example, this does not type check

```
\cons nil -> 5 `cons` 3 `cons` nil
```

nor does this

```
\(#) -> 5 # 3 # nil
```

Although both of these do

```
\cons nil -> 5 `cons` nil
\(#) nil -> 5 # nil
```

Is there a way to assign infixites to operators in lambdas. I tried

```
infixr 5 #
foo = \(#) nil -> 5 # 3 # nil
```

which gives an error for no definition of `#` and

```
foo = \(infixr 5 #) nil -> 5 # 3 # nil
```

which is just a syntax error.

What can I do?

Answer (score 16):

Fixity declarations can be local but must accompany definitions, so you'd have to write something like

```
foo cons nil = 'a' # 'b' # nil
  where (#) = cons
        infixr 5 #
```

or

```
foo = \cons nil -> let (#) = cons; infixr 5 # in 'a' # 'b' # nil
```

etc.

Comment: Nice indeed! Is this part of Haskell98, Haskell2010, or just GHC?

Comment: I especially like the let version.

Comment: It is Haskell 98. The syntax of let and where involves "decls", which includes type signatures, fixity declarations and function and pattern bindings.

Comment: please don't write the `let` version